# The use of the `by` parameter in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning to work with R and more specifically the data.table package.
Now I have found out that sometimes I try to intuitively solve things in ways that don't work with data.table.
Specifically when I am trying to apply the same operation to each row in a data.table and often using that operation to fill a new column or modify an existing one.
For example I created the next command to apply on the table I pasted below too. In the beginning the column C was non-existent, but I created that by applying the correct method.

```
DT[,C:=ifelse(nchar(unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1]) == 4,paste("0",unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1],sep=""),unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1])]
```

But applying this command only gives me the value 10:00 in every row of C..
table:

```
Id          A           B         C
 1         41 10:00-10:15     10:00
 2         38   9:15-9:30     09:15
 3         39   9:30-9:45     09:30
 4         40  9:45-10:00     09:45
 5         57 14:00-14:15     14:00
 6         59 14:30-14:45     14:30
 7         58 14:15-14:30     14:15
 8         56 13:45-14:00     13:45
 9         91 22:30-22:45     22:30
10         89 22:00-22:15     22:00
```

Then somewhere (I'm sorry I lost the link) on StackOverflow I found someone doing the same thing but using the `by` parameter. This would make my command like this:"

```
DT[,C:=ifelse(nchar(unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1]) == 4,paste("0",unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1],sep=""),unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1]),by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

This gives me the correct results. Basically the same as:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(DT))
{
  DT[row,C:=ifelse(nchar(unlist(strsplit(DT[row,B],"-"))[1]) == 4,paste("0",unlist(strsplit(DT[row,B],"-"))[1],sep=""),unlist(strsplit(DT[row,B],"-"))[1])]
}
```

This confused me because reading the help page for data.table about `by` it says:

> A single unquoted column name, a list() of expressions of column names, a single character string containing comma separated column names (where spaces are significant since column names may contain spaces even at the start or end), or a character vector of column names.

So this made me think `by` was only to point to columns, but here I am using it for rows... Can someone explain what is going on?

---

Additional question after comments:
When I use the following code

```
test <- data.table(matrix(1:10))
test[,V2:=V1+2]

# V1 V2
#  1  3
#  2  4
#  3  5
#  4  6
#  5  7
#  6  8
#  7  9
#  8 10
#  9 11
# 10 12
```

I get the expected result. V2 contains the value of V1 upped by 2.
Why does the same method not work in the case of my initial code above, where I ask the data.table to split every value of column B and put the resulting string into the new column.

Comment: `by` refers to columns of grouping variables. Here you create the grouping variable (with a group for each row) on the fly. You do not refer to rows.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but do you know why it does not work without `by`?

Comment: It doesn't work without by because you are assigning the same value to each row. For example `unlist(strsplit(B,"-"))[1]` returns one single value which is recycled so the whole columns equal that.

Comment: Hmmm, but B refers to the entire column of B and not only one value?
I still don't understand why in some cases the operation is applied to the entire column and in this case it is only applied to the first row and then recycled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsplit` returns a list and you need the first element of each list element. This can be achieved using `lapply` or one of it's relatives. Here I use `vapply`, which returns a vector. Padding with zero is done in a seperate step, since `ifelse` is not the best option here for performance.

```
DT <- read.table(text="Id          A           B         C
 1         41 10:00-10:15     10:00
 2         38   9:15-9:30     09:15
 3         39   9:30-9:45     09:30
 4         40  9:45-10:00     09:45
 5         57 14:00-14:15     14:00
 6         59 14:30-14:45     14:30
 7         58 14:15-14:30     14:15
 8         56 13:45-14:00     13:45
 9         91 22:30-22:45     22:30
10         89 22:00-22:15     22:00", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)



library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
#extract first entry in each list element
DT[, C := vapply(strsplit(B,"-"), `[`, "string", i = 1)]
#pad with zero 
DT[nchar(C) == 4, C := paste0(0, C)]
#    Id  A           B     C
# 1:  1 41 10:00-10:15 10:00
# 2:  2 38   9:15-9:30 09:15
# 3:  3 39   9:30-9:45 09:30
# 4:  4 40  9:45-10:00 09:45
# 5:  5 57 14:00-14:15 14:00
# 6:  6 59 14:30-14:45 14:30
# 7:  7 58 14:15-14:30 14:15
# 8:  8 56 13:45-14:00 13:45
# 9:  9 91 22:30-22:45 22:30
#10: 10 89 22:00-22:15 22:00
```

Using `by` as you show in the questiobn is an alternative to using `*apply` here. However, I wouldn't expect it to be faster in this example since data.table probably doesn't optimize the content of the loop.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I am achieving by putting `unlist(strsplitList)[1]` in the command?
Ow wait...it's not returning one list but the whole column B split? (going out testing)

Comment: No, that command turns the list into a vector and extracts the first element of that vector (which is exactly one value).

Comment: Wow, so that's where things go awry!
That took me long to figure out :') Thanks for your help!

Comment: And thanks for the optimization advice :)
I just benchmarked those two options and `ifelse` is indeed a little slower than seperate padding. 5.58 vs 3.31 on 1000 runs.

Comment: @Gullydwarf Benchmarks depend on the size of the data.table. I expect that the performance difference would be more significant if the data.table is truly large (i.e., millions of rows).